# jquery ready function not getting hit inside function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

So my jquery ready function isn't getting called.  I put a breakpoint at the line and it hits it, but nothing inside the function is hit.  Here's the js, which was generated from coffeescript.

```
(function() {

  jQuery(function() {
     return alert('working');
  });

}).call(this);
```

So the breakpoint at the jQuery line gets hit, but not the alert.  Any ideas?

Comment: put this line in: `if(!window.jQuery) { alert("no jquery!");}` and see what happens

Comment: WickyNilliams: Nope, no alert there.  jQuery seems to be okay.

Comment: hmmm, strange. The answer below proves the code itself isn't an issue. Anything logged to the console?

Comment: This seems to be an asset pipeline issue.  If I precompile, it starts working.  However, any changes I make then aren't picked up and I have to precompile again.  Bah, this is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell its working:

http://jsfiddle.net/thundercracker/dbdyC/

---

EDIT:
maybe you could try to make the function self-executing since its not working on your end?

```
(function() {

  jQuery((function() {
     return alert('working');
  })());

}).call(this);​
```

Comment: I should add I'm not seeing any errors in the javascript console.

Comment: Maybe you don't have jQuery included? only thing I can think of