# Assets only work in dev if I precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

So we've upgraded an app from rails 3.0.7 to rails 3.2.  We deploy to heroku so we precompile locally before doing so.  Now I've got this problem where my js files only work locally in dev if I precompile first.  Of course this means that if I change something, I have to precompile all over again.  I've tried to do an assets:clean, but then my js stops working.  Or rather, it doesn't work correctly.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799823/jquery-ready-function-not-getting-hit-inside-function)

I've also tried setting my config.assets.prefix to "assets-dev" to server them out of a different location.  My other rails projects don't have this problem.  Here's my relevant settings in environment/development.rb

```
  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  #compile on the fly
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Server assets out of asset-dev so they won't conflict with precompiles
  config.assets.prefix = "assets-dev"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure in environments/development.rb you don't need

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: You are correct.  This doesn't fix the problem though. It's still not running any code inside my document ready.

Comment: Are you getting a 404 in your web developer tools for the scripts? What are the paths? Do they match up?

Comment: No, it's loading the scripts. Chrome shows them as loaded as well.  It's just not running anything inside my document ready.  I put a breakpoint on my $(document.ready) line and it hits that, but nothing inside.  See this link.   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799823/jquery-ready-function-not-getting-hit-inside-function)

Comment: Make a plain test.html.erb and inside that: <script> $(function() { alert("Works!") }); </script>

Comment: I'm wondering if you have some Chrome add-on causing a problem?

Comment: Hmm, that did not work.  I also tried it in firefox with no luck.  No errors in the console though saying undefined $

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14874/discussion-between-todd-baur-and-avoidiam)